# How can I try/catch an exception for a negative number in c#?

Tags: c#, try-catch, square

My program is simply a square root
I take an integer from the user in a TextBox and give the result using the function Math.Sqrt
in the other TextBox.
What I am trying to do now is to show a MessageBox using try/catch exceptions that tells the user
he can't use a negative number I used if statement but did not show the MessageBox just getting NaN value, please if anyone could help

```
        int num1;
        try
        {
            num1 = System.Convert.ToInt32((textBox1.Text));
            textBox2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(num1));
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data type is wrong");
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            num1 = 0;
            if (num1 < 0)

            MessageBox.Show("Number must be positive");
            
        }
```

Comment: `num1 = 0; if (num1 < 0) { ... }`. `num1` is always going to be `0`, so `num1 < 0` is always going to be false

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this using an exception? Seems a strange way of going about it. Just testing if the number is less than zero, before taking the Sqrt, is a lot simpler and the intent clearer. You need to catch the format exception (or use TryParse as McNets says) but the rest just becomes `if (num1 < 0) { /* msg box shows error */ } else { /* take sqrt and display it */ }`

Comment: And additionally have a look at: int.TryParse

Comment: Catching an exception to just force a positive value is kind of overhead, you can simply do num1 = Math.Abs(num1); instead.

Comment: I don't know about that Jonas, by default I'd prefer not to make assumptions about the user's intent when they've make an invalid entry. Depends on the context, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, exceptions are used to manage rare events. Manage exceptions it's costly. In your case, maybe normal a typo error or even a negative number. It's better manage as a normal thing.

```
int num1;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num1) && num1 >= 0)
{
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(num1));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must enter a positive number");
}
```

If you need use try/catch:

```
try
{
   int num1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
   if (num1 >= 0)
   {
       textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(num1));
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("You must enter a positive number");
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I must use the try/catch way in this program, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [Math.Sqrt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sqrt?view=net-6.0). This function doesn't throw an exception when number is negative. This is first reason why the code for `catch(Exception){}` is not being executed.

Secondly you are setting

```
num1 = 0;
```

and then next checking

```
if(num<0){} // This will always be false
```

Anyways I recommend to check the `num1` value before you calculate the root

```
int num1;
try
{
    num1 = System.Convert.ToInt32((textBox1.Text));
    if (num1 < 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Number must be positive");
    else
        textBox2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(num1));
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data type is wrong");
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved me